# Is there any way to find what \settextfont[Scale=XXXXX] equivalent to font size?

Tags: xetex, fontsize

I want to know how can I match `\settextfont[Scale=XXX}` with MS word font size?

For example if I want to write essay in font of 14 in Ms word what should I set instead of XXX in `\settextfont[Scale=XXX}`?

*EDIT Marco Daniel:* The package `xepersian` provides the command `settextfont`

Comment: `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}`; it's not sufficient to state the size of the main font: all the document's parameters must be adjusted. There are also the **extreport** and **extbook** classes.

Comment: It seems I did not quite understand the question. Is the text in persian?

Comment: @Andy Yes I write in persian